# Convert InputStream to base64 and then to byte array

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need a byte array, but the requirement is like first I need to convert the input stream to base64 and then the base64 to byte array.

I have tried directly to the byte array, but the requirement is like need to convert the InputStream to base64 and then byte[].

```java
InputStream input = ....
byte[] byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(input);
```

Comment: Why do you need that intermediate conversion? Are you going to process that Base64 string somehow later?

Comment: At a guess, the input stream is an already base64 encoded stream, so it's convert *from* a base64 string slurped from the input stream into the byteArray. The Base64.Decoder class has a `wrap` method to wrap the decoding of an input stream

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Base64` from `java.util` package to encode your stream to base 64

Something like this:

```
    String initialString = "original text";
    InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(initialString.getBytes());

    byte[] byteEncoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(IOUtils.toByteArray(input));
```

The method is `Base64.getEncoder().encode` and have 3 candidates:

- `public byte[] encode(byte[] src`
- `public int encode(byte[] src,byte[] dst)`
- `public ByteBuffer encode(ByteBuffer buffer)`

Hoping that help

Comment: Hi , But the requirement is like first convert the InputStream(ie. PDF) into Base64 and then convert that to a Byte array[].   I already used byte[] documentByteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream); byte[] encodedArray = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(documentByteArray);  But doesn't work for me